# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'link.area' in 'where clause'

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I migrated my magento site ..it migrated successfully bt when i import database it keep on showing error "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'link.area' in 'where clause'"

what does that mean??? please help

Comment: Please let me know the version of magento? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There must be some area column. Please check sql script of every extension for exact details of area column.